# How to pass dynamic PHP variable as parameter in window.open method

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a window pop up using window.open method in javascript, it works fine simply without any dynamic variable passing, but i am not getting how to pass the php variable inside the function to make it functional in another window.

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
<?php
   if(isset($d->retweeted_status->id_str)){
      $tweetId = $d->retweeted_status->id_str;
   } else{
      $tweetId = $d->id_str;
   }
   $myUrl = "retweetDetails.php?id=".$tweetId;
<?
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('retweetDetails.php', 'my_new_window','width=625, height=400');" class="btn btn-default twitter_button_retweets"><?php echo $d->retweet_count; ?> Retweets </a>
```

I want to pass this `$myUrl` variable as a url parameter which will reflect in popup window.

Thanks

Comment: `window.open('<?=$myUrl?>'`?

Comment: Change `<?` to `?>` before `<a` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $myUrl; ?>', 'my_new_window','width=625, height=400');" class="btn btn-default twitter_button_retweets"><?php echo $d->retweet_count; ?> Retweets </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
   if(isset($d->retweeted_status->id_str)){
      $tweetId = $d->retweeted_status->id_str;
   } else{
      $tweetId = $d->id_str;
   }
   $myUrl = "retweetDetails.php?id=".$tweetId;
<?
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $myUrl; ?>', 'my_new_window','width=625, height=400');" class="btn btn-default twitter_button_retweets"><?php echo $d->retweet_count; ?> Retweets </a>
```